# Why need container_of when kmalloc already returns the pointer to memory location?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

kmalloc() returns a pointer to the memory location allocated during initialization and if one makes the struct containing cdev point to it, why would one need to do container_of in the file operations open call to get the address of struct containing cdev again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you're referring to something like this:

http://www.cs.uni.edu/~diesburg/courses/dd/code/scull/pipe.c

```
static int scull_p_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    struct scull_pipe *dev;

    dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_pipe, cdev);
    // ...
```

And `kmalloc` is used like this:

```
    scull_p_devices = kmalloc(scull_p_nr_devs * sizeof(struct scull_pipe), GFP_KERNEL);
```

Where `struct scull_pipe` is:

```
struct scull_pipe {
        wait_queue_head_t inq, outq;       /* read and write queues */
        char *buffer, *end;                /* begin of buf, end of buf */
        int buffersize;                    /* used in pointer arithmetic */
        char *rp, *wp;                     /* where to read, where to write */
        int nreaders, nwriters;            /* number of openings for r/w */
        struct fasync_struct *async_queue; /* asynchronous readers */
        struct semaphore sem;              /* mutual exclusion semaphore */
        struct cdev cdev;                  /* Char device structure */
};
```

The reason for using `container_of` is that in `scull_p_open` callback you don't have pointer to `struct scull_pipe` instance, but you have access to `cdev` member of `struct scull_pipe` structure (through `inode->i_cdev`). In order to get the container address of `cdev` (in other words address of `struct scull_pipe` instance), you need to use `container_of`:

```
struct scull_pipe *dev;

dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_pipe, cdev);
```

Comment: So container_of returns the pointer to the start of struct type and not the instance ? Why would we need that ?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear, it should be "in order to get the the container address of `cdev` (in other words the address of the `struct scull_pipe` instance).

Comment: Okay , so if I do kmalloc individually for each device, instead of just multiplying with no. of devices is it the same thing then?

Comment: It still doesn't matter, because kmalloc returns the address of the `struct scull_pipe` (let's call that instance `i` - it's the value returned from `kmalloc`) that it allocated which you don't have in `open` function - in there you have `i->c_dev` address, and not the address of `i`. In order to get the value of `i` from `i->c_dev` you need to subtract some words from `i->c_dev` (for all previous fields in the structure) - that's essentially what `container_of` macro is doing. Let me know if this still doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think I didn't tell you the whole thing. I am storing the kmalloc return values in an array which I have declared golbally so I can just use that array to get the pointer for any struct instance .

Comment: Yes, in that case you don't need `container_of`. You need `container_of` only if you're accessing it via `inode->i_cdev`.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for the help :) . Appreciate it. Can I ask another question if you have time ?

Comment: Better make another question on SO :-)